# How do I add a new user to an embedded Linux system by hand?

Tags: users

I have a system which was designed for use by root only and I want to run an FTP server on it. The software I use handles authentication by using same username and password as OS itself. To me it looks safer to have another user for FTP data transfer and another which would just run FTP server.

So here's my problem: As I've said, system was designed to be used only by root and there's no useradd or anything similar, as far as I can see. Is it possible to add user by hand?

I'm running OpenWRT Backfire 10.03.1-rc4, if it matters, but generic answers would be best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very roughly:

```
# cp /etc/passwd /etc/passwd.bak # just in case you e.g. forget one of the >s
# echo 'ftpuser:x:1000:1000:ftp user:/home/ftpuser:/bin/sh' >>/etc/passwd
# cp /etc/shadow /etc/shadow.bak
# echo 'ftpuser:x:15020:0:99999:7:::' >>/etc/shadow
# cp /etc/group /etc/group.bak
# echo 'ftpuser:x:1000:' >>/etc/group
# cp /etc/gshadow /etc/gshadow.bak
# echo 'ftpuser:x:1000:' >>/etc/gshadow
# passwd ftpuser
# mkdir /home/ftpuser
# chown ftpuser:ftpuser /home/ftpuser
```

You should of course make sure the username, user id, and group id are available.  Also, unless the account needs shell access for some reason, set the shell to something like `/bin/false` or `/sbin/nologin` (if the latter is available).

Comment: Downvoted for suggesting /bin/sh as a shell for a ftp-only user. Use `/bin/false` or something similar to make sure the FTP user can't get shell access, or better yet, set up scponly in a chroot (see [http://sublimation.org/scponly/wiki/index.php/Install] for instructions)

Comment: Note that he wants both a sending user and a server user.  The former may well be a shell account.

Comment: Good point, but I'm kind of worried about the fact that he's trying to add a server user to a distro that's apparently specifically built /not/ to have them...

Comment: It's not a distribution *per se*; he's doing this on a router running the OpenWRT firmware, which is something of an advanced usage but well within the kinds of things people do with OpenWRT.

Comment: What if I want to add the user to more than 1 group?

Comment: Then the person doing so likely has a very poor understanding of what to do with an embedded system.  I forget if `shadow-utils` is available on OpenWRT.  Were I up to such a (silly) thing I'd go find an ancient version of `shadow` and statically cross-compile the package.  But first I'd make sure it was impossible to solve the problem any other way.